# Next without For VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to be stuck on what should be a basic issue. I am trying to code all my filters together with VBA. I am new to the language and I think I copied this exactly from a file on Lynda.com but I am stuck. Any help would be great. When I try to run a macro I get a next with out for error.

```
  Dim pt As PivotTable
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For Each pt In Active.Sheet.PivotTables
    With pt.PivotFields("Parent Company")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Milestone")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Lead Status")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Lead Source")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 4
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Contact Owner:Full Name")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 5
    With pt.PivotFields("Company: Company")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Next pt
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing an End With after .Position = 5

Comment: How many `Withs` and how many `End Withs` do you have?

Comment: First line should be `Sub test()` or whatever name you want for your sub-routine to match the `End Sub`

Comment: Also consider for the  xlPageField you could loop an array so you don't need all the With statements. Just one for the xlPage field setting and one for the row. I have pasted an example here: https://pastebin.com/NqXPeazL

Comment: `Active.Sheet.PivotTables` should be `ActiveSheet.PivotTables`

Comment: Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a helper function when repeating code.  This will reduce input error, code clutter, and make the code easier to read and debug.

[image: Object Browser Demo]

Using the Object Browser, I will copy the Function or Objects' parameters and data types that I want to pass to the helper function.  In this way, I will be able to use Intellisense when calling it.

[image: Intellisense Demo]

---

```
Sub Test()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        setPivotFields pt, "Parent Company", xlPageField, 1
        setPivotFields pt, "Milestone", xlPageField, 1
        setPivotFields pt, "Lead Status", xlPageField, 2
        setPivotFields pt, "Lead Source", xlPageField, 3
        setPivotFields pt, "Contact Owner:Full Name", xlPageField, 4
        setPivotFields pt, "Contact Owner:Full Name", xlPageField, 5
        setPivotFields pt, "Company: Company", xlPageField, 1
    Next pt
End Sub

Sub setPivotFields(pt As PivotTable, FieldName As String, Orientation As XlPivotFieldOrientation, Position As Variant)
    With pt.PivotFields("Company: Company")
        .Orientation = Orientation
        .Position = Position
    End With
End Sub
```